# Testing large dataset for normality - how and is it reliable?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, large-data

I'm examining a part of my dataset containing 46840 double values ranging from 1 to 1690 grouped in two groups. In order to analyze the differences between these groups I started by examining the distribution of the values in order to pick the right test.

Following a guide on testing for normality, I did a qqplot, histogram & boxplot.

[image]

[image]
[image]

This doesn't seem to be a normal distribution. Since the guide states somewhat correctly that a purely graphical examination isn't sufficient I also want to test the distribution for normality.

Considering the size of the dataset and the limitation of the shapiro-wilks test in R , how should the given distribution be tested for normality and considering the size of the dataset, is this even reliable? ([See accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781798/seeing-if-data-is-normally-distributed-in-r/7788452#7788452))

**Edit:**

The limitation of the Shapiro-Wilk test I'm referring to is that the dataset to be tested is limited to 5000 points. 
To cite [another good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427692/perform-a-shapiro-wilk-normality-test/15427746#15427746) concerning this topic:

> An additional issue with the Shapiro-Wilk's test is that when you feed
>   it more data, the chances of the null hypothesis being rejected
>   becomes larger. So what happens is that for large amounts of data even
>   very small deviations from normality can be detected, leading to
>   rejection of the null hypothesis event hough for practical purposes
>   the data is more than normal enough.
>
> [...] Luckily shapiro.test protects the user from the above described
>   effect by limiting the data size to 5000.

**As to why I am testing for normal distribution in the first place:**

Some hypothesis tests assume normal distribution of the data. I want to know whether or not I can use these tests.

Comment: There's no point testing; every test of any use at all, a any reasonable significance level will clearly reject. Whatever guide you're reading has misled you. What do you mean by 'reliable' exactly. What 'limitation' of the Shapiro-Wilk do you refer to? I would very nearly agree with the statement in the answer you link to ... "I have never come across a situation where a normal test is the right thing to do" (I've seen at least once situation where I think it's the right thing to do, but people almost always do it for bad reasons).

Comment: @Glen_b: incidentally, [I found myself using Shapiro–Wilk the other day](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18773/10518) to quantify the evidence against the null, which someone over on Academia had mistakenly assumed to be greater than it was from a sample of grades. I wonder if that was defensible usage.

Comment: @NickStauner my response grew much too long for a single comment and I don't want to hijack this question with a string of comments about your post there. Possibilities: We talk in chat, or you post a question about it (to which I could post an extensive answer), or we discuss it in some other way, such as email.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see why you'd bother. It's plainly not normal – in this case, graphical examination appears sufficient to me. You've got plenty of observations from what appears to be a nice clean gamma distribution. Just go with that. [kolmogorov-smirnov](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-smirnov) it if you must – I'll recommend a reference distribution.

`x=rgamma(46840,2.13,.0085);qqnorm(x);qqline(x,col='red')`
[image]

`hist(rgamma(46840,2.13,.0085))`
[image]

`boxplot(rgamma(46840,2.13,.0085))`
[image]

As I always say, "See [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/32036)," particularly [@MånsT's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30053/32036), which points out that different analyses have different sensitivities to different violations of normality assumptions. If your distribution is as close to mine as it looks, you've probably got skew $\approx1.4$ and kurtosis $\approx5.9$ ("excess kurtosis" $\approx2.9$). That's liable to be a problem for a lot of tests. If you can't just find a test with more appropriate parametric assumptions or none at all, maybe you could transform your data, or at least conduct a sensitivity analysis of whatever analysis you have in mind.